# in nested brackets which would be outermost bracket

Tags: education

i wanna know that in an algebric equation of 2 level nested brackets which format of nested bracket is correct

{4[3+5(3+2)]}

[4{3+5(3+2)}]

is curly would be outermost or square

Comment: Whichever one you like.

Comment: is there any conventions for it